# Use loop/with_item to build a variable list

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to dynamically build a list using loop/with_item:

```
- name: processes
  package: ""
  set_fact:
    plugin_options: "{{ CollectFileDescriptor true | CollectContextSwitch true | <ProcessMatch   '{{ item.name }}'  > | CollectFileDescriptor false | CollectContextSwitch true | </ProcessMatch>}}"
    loop:
       - { name: proc1 }
       - { name: proc2 }
```

so in the end I should have for plugin_options:

```
CollectFileDescriptor true 
CollectContextSwitch true 
<ProcessMatch   proc1  > 
 CollectFileDescriptor false 
 CollectContextSwitch true 
</ProcessMatch>
CollectFileDescriptor true 
CollectContextSwitch true 
<ProcessMatch   proc2  > 
 CollectFileDescriptor false 
 CollectContextSwitch true 
</ProcessMatch>
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world would you think the use of jinja2 pipelines is appropriate for constructing XML elements?

```
- set_fact:
    plugin_options: >-
      {% for item in ["proc1", "proc2"] %}
      CollectFileDescriptor true 
      CollectContextSwitch true 
      <ProcessMatch  {{item}} > 
      CollectFileDescriptor false 
      CollectContextSwitch true 
      </ProcessMatch>
      {% endfor %}
```